# Problems with C file writing

Tags: c, file, io

I have problems writing to file, this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("\x1B[31mError::%s takes exactly one argument!\n\x1B[0m",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char string[100];

    FILE* file=fopen(argv[1],"w");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("\x1B[31mFile is invalid!\x1B[0m\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(!feof(stdin))
    {
        scanf("%s",string);
        fprintf(file,"%s\n",string);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

it should take input with scanf and writing to the file until i enter the end of file character (ctrl+Z), when it's finished running,the file i opened is empty. This code structure is also suggested in the deitel & deitel book, Do you know what's wrong here?
Also, i would like to know how can i take a whole phrase with scanf instead of a single word each time.. if i do scanf("%[^\n]",string)
the program gets confused and as soon as i write something, it will go in a loop writing the same thing over and over, and the file will become like 1,7Gb large.. help!

Comment: Using `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong.

Comment: ctrl+Z  is SIGTSTP which will stop the process execution forcefully, data will not be save into file.

Comment: Turns out that the eof key is different based on OS,it's ctrl+D not Z thanks,
but i would also like to know why scanf("%[^\n]",string) does not work?

Answer (score 0):

when user will press `ctrl+z` your process(`a.out`) will receive `signal` no `20` internally and your process will be `stopped` but data will `not` be saved because program got terminated `abnormally`.

you can type `man 7 signal` on `terminal` and check the `default actio`n of `ctrl+z`. So now you need to modify `ctrl+z` by-default action ? how ? use `signal()` or `sigaction()`.

whenever `ctrl+z` is pressed, jumps to `isr()` and there `save` the current process status using `exit()` system call. `ctrl+z` is signal no `20`.

I did small modifications in your code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
void isr(int n)
{
        if(n == 20)//if ctrl+z is pressed then condition will be true 
        {
                printf("in isr :\n");
                exit(0);//exit(0) is normal termination of process i.e it will save current process context
        }
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
        if(argc!=2)
        {
                printf("\x1B[31mError::%s takes exactly one argument!\n\x1B[0m",argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }

        char string[100];

        FILE* file=fopen(argv[1],"w");
        if(file==NULL)
        {
                printf("\x1B[31mFile is invalid!\x1B[0m\n");
                return 1;
        }

        while(!feof(stdin))
        {
                signal(20,isr);//when user presses ctrl+z it will jump to isr()
                scanf("%s",string);
                fprintf(file,"%s\n",string);

        }

        fclose(file);
        return 0;
}
```

once go through man pages of `signal()` and `exit()`.